# Easiest way to get skype user presence using dotnetcore?

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, lync, ucma, ucwa

I would like to know what is the easiest method to getting user presence for a website that exists on a server? We are using a web based application in dotnetCore

Is there any benefit to using ucma vs ucwa vs something else when getting user presence?

Currently I am using Lync SDK

```
lyncClient = LyncClient.GetClient()
Contact usercontact = lyncClient.ContactManager.GetContactByUri("sip:" + email);
var userPresence = GetStatus(Convert.ToInt32(usercontact.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.Availability)));
```

but once I deploy the app to the server I get an error since there is no lync client installed on the server.

Is there a better way to do this without installing anything on a server?

Answer (score 2):

The Lync Client SDK is basically a SDK that remotely controls the currently running instance of the Skype Client. (as you have found out)  Not really useful for applications running on servers.

The options you have are:

- [UCWA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/unifiedcommunicationswebapi2_0) - this is a web based API where you can log in as a user and query other users presence states, this will work with on-prem and on-line versions of SfB
- [UCMA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucma/unified-communications-managed-api-ucma-5-0-sdk-documentation) - this is a C# based API where you create SIP endpoints (you can think of them as instances of a Skype client) that you can use to query other users presence states in two main modes, this mainly only works with on-prem SfB setups.  It can work with SfB using on-prem federation to the SfB on-line users, but this still requires a on-prem SfB setup.

UCMA modes:

- [Client Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucma/client-platforms) - this basically allows you to create a SIP endpoint for a Skype user (i.e. you need a skype user login details to use)
- [Server Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucma/server-platforms) - this allows you can setup a "trusted application" that can use "trusted application endpoints" to do things like query for other user presence states.  This does not require any user login details but is way more involved onsite application setup and is best for "server" installs.

Which one you use depends a lot on the details of what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks so if my website resides on an intranet server then does the server need any type of installation or is it plug and play? I deploy and it works the same as if im running on my local machine

Comment: If the machine running it is on the internet (i.e. not part of the domain where SfB lives), then I think it's best to use UCWA.

Comment: Ok yea its all the same domain since its intranet.

Comment: Sorry I misread your comment.  For UCWA / UCMA client platform, you can develop it on your machine and deploy it fine.  For UCMA Server platform, you can't as the trusted application setup is tied to a specific machine (or set of machines) via certificates / DNS resolution.  Altho you can develop a UCMA client platform and switch to server platform easy enough once you understand how it works.